# pip wheel' requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, devstack, python-wheel

I am trying to run devstack `./stack.sh`, however it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: 'pip wheel' requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support. To fix this, run: pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I tried different commands such as:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or

```
sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
```

However in all cases I get this:

```
The directory '/home/nik/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: looks like `stack.sh` is calling `/usr/bin/python` but `pip` belongs to `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: when I uninstalled setuptools, it gave me an error that there is not setuptools available, so I guess it is pointing to the correct directory.